# Ruby 'sort' puts 1XX values before the 8X values in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have this simple array which I want to order from the lower to the higher number:

```
"80", "84", "115", "98", "128", "131", "132", "128", "139", "140", "141", "142", "142", "124", "144", "145", "148", "149", "152", "97"
```

To sort it, I use `sort`, but the output is not the one I'd expect.

This is my code:

```
def try_order
  unordered = ["80", "84", "115", "98", "128", "131", 
               "132", "128", "139", "140", "141", "142", 
               "142", "124", "144", "145", "148", "149", "152", "97"]
  p "Unordered list is #{unordered}."

  ordered = unordered.sort

  p "Ordered list is #{ordered}."
end

try_order
```

And the output is as follows:

```
"Unordered list is 80841159812813113212813914014114214212414414514814915297."
"Ordered list is 11512412812813113213914014114214214414514814915280849798."
```

As you can see, the ordered list is not starting with the lower number, which is 80, but putting the 3-digit numbers which start with a 1 first.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You're missing that a string is not a number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is this:

```
unordered.sort_by(&:to_i)
```

Comment: Ah yes. Forgot about it :(

Answer (score 7):

It's because you're sorting strings, not numbers. Cast to integers for sorting.

```
unordered.map(&:to_i).sort.map(&:to_s)
```

If you keep the original array as numbers, then you eliminate the problem (and gain better sorting performance (because now you don't have to map the array twice)).